# What am I supposed to look for in the question "What is the total resistance between $X$ and $Y$?"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I'm not really concerned with answering the question but more so what I'm trying to look for. The question is

> "Three resistors are connected as shown. What is the total resistance between $X$ and $Y$?"

Again, I don't really need help with understanding the theory but more so, understanding what I'm supposed to find in the end. Am I supposed to subtract the resistance at X by the resistance at Y? Or add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I assume $X$ and $Y$ are named points in a circuit. What the question really means is:

If you applied a voltage $U$ between the points $X$ and $Y$, what is the value of $R$ such that $U = R I$, where $I$ is the current flowing between $X$ and $Y$? So effectively it is asking to find the total resistance of all paths connecting $X$ and $Y$. The "between" that apparently confused you, does not mean any difference, but refers to "if we apply a *potential difference between* $X$ and $Y$ ..."

Answer (score -2):

No, you are supposed to find the effective resistance of the conducting paths between X and Y.

Comment: What does effective resistance mean?

Comment: Hi Tahan, assuming there are several paths between X and Y, each with a particular resistance, you can replace them by a single path of equivalent resistance. The resistance of that equivalent single path is what you are being asked to determine.